# JQuery Multiple Hidden Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML;

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">
  www.andrewspiers.co.uk        
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="www.andrewspiers.co.uk">
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
  wikipedia.org        
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="wikipedia.org">
</li>
</ul>
```

The plan is to add a button to each row and then get the value from the hidden field when the button is clicked.

I have this;

```
alert( $('input[name="url"]').val() );
```

But that returns the value of the first row no matter which button is clicked.

Comment: you mean to say , the row's button is clicked : you need value of hidden input for that specific row only ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('li').find('input[name="url"]').val())
})
```

You need to use `$(this)` within the click function to refer to that specific element and then traverse the DOM accordingly (multiple ways to skin a cat on this one) to get the hidden input.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fuo585rb/)**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your buttons are placed inside the same `li`, you need a more specific selector:

```
alert( $(this).siblings('input[name="url"]').val() );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add buttons like this :

```
 $('.list-group-item').each(function(){
   $(this).append('<input class="clicked" type="button" value="Click me"/>')
 })
```

YOu can then get value of each hidden according to the button like this:

```
 $('.clicked').on('click',function(){
  var hiddenval =$(this).parent().find('input[name="url"]').val();
  console.log(hiddenval);
 })
```